# Sending Ether from contract to the sender

Tags: solidity, ganache, transfer

This is a very common question. I am trying to withdraw fund from the contract. I have tried send,transfer and call but the transaction hash always shows 0 value transferred

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

function withdraw(address payable _to, uint256 _amount) public returns (bool){
    bool sent = _to.send(_amount);
    return sent;
}
```

[image]

I can see the amount is right in the method request, but not sure what i am doing wrong

In addition, I did verify the contract has enough balance

[image]

I am not sure, what i am doing wrong

Comment: We can’t see the pictures fix the post :)

Comment: If you click on the image, it expands. @MajdTL. Do you want me to capture more info from ganache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works as expected. send method works instead of the other one FYI